# Is 二ヶ所 slang for something else?

Tags: slang

Can't find this in the dictionary. Is this the slang form of something else? What does it mean?

Comment: Where'd you see it?

Comment: Saw it on twitter.

Comment: Oh, actually I found ヶ所 in the dictionary. It has the same meaning as カ所. What was the sentence that made you think it was slang?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like にかしょ, so probably 二カ所 (two places) or 二箇所 (two parts).